# Image capture (photograph) in Directshow on Windows Mobile is too slow- suggestions?

Tags: windows-mobile, directshow, image-capture

I'm using Directshow to capture images on a winmo device.  I've based my native code on the "CameraCapture" example found in the Windows Mobile 6 sdk, with a few minor tweaks (simplified the graph, added a live preview window, upped the photo resolution, etc...).

**My problem is that the call to IAMVideoControl::SetMode() to actually "take" the photo is taking too long to finish.**  When I call it, it runs asynchronously, takes a couple of seconds, and then plays back a camera shutter sound when the photo file gets created.  It's equally slow on the unmodified CameraCapture example as it is in my own code, so nothing that I've added seems to be causing this problem.

I've worked around the asynchronous part by listening for dshow events, but I'm having trouble finding a faster way to take a photo.  Annoyingly, I also haven't been able to find any way to silence the shutter sound yet (?).  This is all pretty disappointing since the Microsoft "CameraCaptureDialog" instantly takes photos at equal (and higher) resolutions.

*[EDIT]: The speed comment was made based on how I remembered it running and a recent test with another device, but after seeing the comments below, I retested with the standard CCD- it's just as slow. Unless anyone has any tricks to make this faster (or to silence the shutter noise), I'd say I'm gonna have to live with what I've got. THANKS AGAIN!*

**Any suggestions on what I might look into to speed this process up?  Is there a faster way to go about taking a photo via Directshow?**

thanks again!

Comment: What device are you using that takes digital photos instantly, with a live preview window going especially?  I've worked with the CameraCapture example before, and if I remember correctly it took a couple of seconds to switch the filter from the low resolution used for the live preview to the high resolution used to take the still, and that seemed to be a fundamental problem.  Every WM device I've ever used suffered from that long delay (every digital camera I've ever used, too).

Comment: Agreed, every device I've used takes forever from the capture request to the actual capture, even from the built-in app.

Comment: Oops! I made that "instant" speed comment from (apparently failing) memory, and the concern was further fueled from a recent side-by-side done with a different device (a smartphone running winmo 6.1). 

I was totally wrong: On the SAME device, the camera capture dialog is just as slow as my dshow code.  The phone WAS instant and seems to be using the CCD, though... same UI, but I guess it was heavily optimised for that particular phone. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way is SampleGrabber, but it will capture frames with the same resolution as preview (as a rule preview resolution equals to screen resolution)